# Alternative to routerState.parent which no longer exists in angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

In angular2 rc5, I had this code.

```
this.router.routerState.parent(this.route).params.forEach((params: Params) => {
    url = params['url'];
    id = +params['id'];
});
```

I had to use this because I was two levels down on my router, and for some reason doing this didn't work.

```
this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        url = params['url'];
        id = +params['id'];
    });
```

I am still happy to do this, but in angular2 the `.parent` method no longer exists on routerState.

Can I achieve what I want, but using a different method that is available in angular 2.0.0?

Comment: I think you can get the `parent` from `ActivatedRoute` and then from there get the `routerState`.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorted this a week ago, i have updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 6):

In case this helps anyone else. Instead of using `.routerState` just use `.parent`

```
// parent params
let url = '';
let id = 0;
this.route.parent.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
    url = params['url'];
    id = +params['id'];
});
```

Comment: worth to mention, `this.route` is of type `ActivatedRoute`.